# Highstocks tooltip Remove the phrase "Week From Monday"

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Hi i'm having some issues getting the tootip display proper information. Right now it displays this.

Here is a sample: [image: sample highstock tooltip]

I want to remove the phrase "Week from Monday" which is appearing before the date. I've tried changing the tooltip object parameter in the chart option but it didn't helped. 
Here is how the chart options look now

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'stock-chart-container',
                alignTicks: true,
            },
            tooltip: {
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    millisecond: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L",
                    second: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S",
                    minute: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M",
                    hour: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M",
                    day: "%A, %b %e, %Y",
                    week: "%m-%d-%Y",
                    month: "%B %Y",
                    year: "%Y"
                }
            },
            navigator: {
                //top: 400
            },
            yAxis: [{
                    title: {
                        text: 'Price'
                    },
                    top: 70,
                    height: 260,
                    lineWidth: 2
                }, {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Volume'
                    },
                    top: 350,
                    height: 100,
                    offset: 0,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                }],
            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'ytd',
                        text: 'YTD'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 5,
                        text: '5y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                selected: null
            },
            title: {
                text: $('#symbol-name').text() + " Stock Price",
            },
            series: [{
                    type: chartGlobalOptions.chartTypes.name,
                    name: $('#symbol-name').text(),
                    data: data.prices,
                    dataGrouping: {
                        units: groupingUnits
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Volume',
                    data: data.volume,
                    yAxis: 1,
                    dataGrouping: {
                        units: groupingUnits
                    }
                }]
        };
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to remove the phrase. I've been trying to achieve this the whole day, without success.

Thanks, in advance

**ANSWER**

I've managed to get the tooltip show proper information with the help of Sebastian. 
Here is how it looks now

```
tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    var d = new Date(this.x);
                    var s = '';
                    s += '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b><br />';
                    $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                        s += '<b><span style = "color:'+point.series.color+';">'+point.series.name +' </span>'+' : '+point.y + '</b><br />';
                    });
                    return s;
                },
                shared: true
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tooltip formatter, which allows to customise tooltip's content.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Yes i thought about doing so. But will changing the tooltip format affect the rest of the tooltip data, for eg.the stock prices, volume. I brought this up because, you see i've built technical indicators for the chart, so the chart adds multiple y-axis and series data upon selecting an indicator. Now the tooltip also shows the data for the new series, and axis and i don't want to change them. So will the changes in tooltip formatter affect the rest of the data along with the date

Comment: Yes its showing properly now. Many thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: No problem, hope that helps ;)